# Pymongo/Discord.py How to add the same user for another server into the database

Tags: discord.py, pymongo, pycord

So, I'm trying to make a command that saves the roles of a user in the MongoDB. But now I'm struggling when the same user executes the command in an other server. How do I check form what server the command was executed and how do I save the roles per server

```
check = cursor.find({"guild_id": guild_id, "_id": self.ctx.author.id})
```

```
        if check is None:
            cursor.insert_one({"guild_id": guild_id, "_id": self.ctx.author.id, "name": str(user_name), "roles": [str(r.id) for r in self.ctx.author.roles[1:]]})
        else:
            cursor.update_one({"guild_id": guild_id, "_id": self.ctx.author.id}, {"$set": {"roles": [str(r.id) for r in self.ctx.author.roles[1:]]}})
```

I tried something like this, but I only get an error that the user already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly: In many ways, it might be smarter *not* to store the role in a database, but instead rely on Discord, and look it up every time you need it, so using something like this for adding roles, for example:

```py
async def change_role(
    self,
    *,
    member: discord.Member,
    role: discord.Role,
):
    try:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
        else:
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        print("could not add role with current permissions") # Do with this what you want
```

However, if you insist on storing them, probably the best way is to use mongo for what it is good at, and store a json object. This is to say that you would create a json object for every server, which contains a list of members, each of which again contains it roles, this way, every member is stored per-server, and can therefore have different settings in each one. Right now, you're using Mongo like it's Postgres, and, in that case, it's probably better to use Postgres.

However, if you do want to do that. I'm expecting the error you're currently getting is because you have set the username field as a unique index in the header. You should remove that setting, as clearly, you now allow for multiple users to exist.

I hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Now my problem is, when I execute the command nothing happens, it doesn't add or change a thing

Comment: Which command, and what do you expect it to do? I'm presuming you mean the helper function I showed, but that is not a command, that is just a helper function you can integrate into the code, to show you how to check for roles, and work around not knowing them via database.

Comment: Already solved my problem, ty anyways!